# Django querying the db uneccessarily for each object

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SkillCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Skill Categories"


class Skill(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        SkillCategory, default=None, null=True, blank=True
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    skill = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)
    avatar = models.URLField(
        max_length=400, default=None, null=True, blank=True
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

My views.py:

```
def ShowUserProfile(request, username=None, template_name='user_profile.html'):
    if not username:
         username = request.user.username

    profile = get_object_or_404(
        UserProfile.objects.select_related(), user__username=username
    )
    ...
```

And in my template I iterate like so:

```
 ...
 {% if skill.category.title == 'Some Skill' %}
   {% for skill in profile.skill.all %}
     <li>{{ skill }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
 ...
```

But if I look at Django Debug Toolbar, I see that for each `Skill`, Django is querying the db to get the `Category`. I am using `select_related` on the `UserProfile` object but it doesn't affect the number of queries. Surely there must be a better way, whereby Django can get all the `Skill` and related `SkillCategory` references in one go?

### Edit

Based on the accurate feedback, the correct view looks like this:

```
def ShowUserProfile(request, username=None, template_name='user_profile.html'):
    if not username:
         username = request.user.username
    profile = get_object_or_404(
        UserProfile.objects.prefetch_related(
            'skill__category'), user__username=username
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select_related` doesn't handle ManyToMany relationships.  Look into [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related), which does handle ManyToMany fields by running two queries and joining the results in Python.

> select_related works by creating an SQL join and including the fields of the related object in the SELECT statement. For this reason, select_related gets the related objects in the same database query. However, to avoid the much larger result set that would result from joining across a ‘many’ relationship, select_related is limited to single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one.
>
> prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using select_related, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one relationships that are supported by select_related. It also supports prefetching of GenericRelation and GenericForeignKey.

Comment: Thanks! So the correct query looks like this: `profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile.objects.prefetch_related('skill__category'), user__username=username)`

Answer (score 1):

Django's `select_related` does not work for `many-to-many` relations.
Check [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)